# Simulation of op-amps in Proteus

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, proteus

I want to simulate the given circuit and get see the outputs from two opamps.

[image]

In reality, I use L272D dual opamp, but for simulation, I decided to use just ideal opamps. The IN+ for the first amplifier is the output of DAC (out of the circuit) which is a sinusoidal signal with an amplitude of 2.5V and an offset of +2.5V. IN+ for U2 is two parallel resistors, one of which is connected to REF194ESZ (4.5V from the datasheet). R3 is actually potentiometer, and I set its value to 1k Ohm. Finally, the load resistors of 4 Ohm are connected to the opamps' outputs. Something that I expect to get is on the image.
[image]

However, what I get from the Transient Analysis graph is

[image]

and from oscilloscope

[image]

yellow - Vout1
blue - Vout2
pink - Vout_DAC

which I suspect is something different...

Am I doing something wrong, or the graph output seems to be correct? Please, give some advice on the simulation of circuits with opamps... I am very new to the simulation in Proteus. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the 2.5V offset? Just asking.

Comment: No, I just expect to get a similar Vout_DAC signal (with an offset) on Vout1, and an inverted signal on Vout2

Comment: what's the voltage supply of the two OpAmps ?

Comment: it's 3.3V, but in a simulation with ideal opamps, does it matter? or I should choose L272D dual opamp after all...

Comment: the output of U1 is Vout1 = 1.2*Vout_dac (so both your offset and ac amplitude get amplified). The output of U2 is Vout2 = Vref-Vout1. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Also never set the oscilloscope in AC mode if you don't know the offset of your signal

Comment: Ideal OpAmp doesn't mean its output can exceed the supply rails, it only means infinite input impedance, infinite gain and zero output impedance.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but why am I getting strange shapes of output signals when I actually should see a sinusoid?

Comment: You should also set all the scope outputs to the same level so it makes more sense

Comment: But then I just straight lines for Vout1 and Vout2 :( as in the transient analysis graph

Comment: Did you correct the supply voltage of the OpAmps ? +15V/-15V is a start

Comment: yes, I supply +15V/-15V to opamps  :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to double check all your connections. There are a few connection dots that shouldn't be there (such as the GND connection of R1) which might indicate the line is terminated before making a connection as Proteus will add a connection dot to a terminated line.

I have built the circuit on my version which is using all the same values as yours, and included an early terminated connection on the output of Vout2, so you can see what I mean with the connection dot:

[image]

When simulating this, here is my output:

[image]

It looks like you have early termination at the inputs of both op-amps which would explain the unexpected outputs, as well as a few other potential ones. If you go back and check, maybe re-do them all so it looks similar to mine, with no additional connection dots, then it should work.